Auth0 token authentication issue
I am using Auth0 for user access with a react front end and .net server. I am trying to pass the JWT token to the backend for verification.
However, when I try to see if the user is authorized when debugging server the user is not authorized and they have 0 claims.
Additionally, if you look at the code below you can see the RoleClaimType is pointed to a custom URL retrieved from the Token.
When debugging the access it seems to point towards the standard microsoft.identity path.
var domain = $"https://{builder.Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/";
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = domain;
    options.Audience = builder.Configuration["Auth0:Audience"];
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,
        RoleClaimType = "https://xxxxxxx/roles"
    };
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("read:messages", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new
    HasScopeRequirement("read:messages", domain)));

    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy =>
    policy.RequireRole("Administrator"));
});

I have tried many different ways to retrieve and validate the token but I am having zero luck.

Can you provide more info about microsoft.identity. It's not clear what you mean.

Have you checked out the content of the token. You can do it using https://jwt.io

Hey Vlad I have checcked the contnet of my token and all parameters/content is there.

It was not microsoft.identity I got that part incorrect. It seems to be pointing towards RoleClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"

Can you try adding this to your AddJwtBearer(options=> options.MapInboundClaims = false;) ? Microsoft might be renaming the claims. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbeareroptions.mapinboundclaims?view=aspnetcore-8.0: the default value of this property is "true"

Thanks for the comment @SoftwareDveloper however this did not resolve the issue. It still seems to be pointing to the same place.

So after some further investiagtion I found my audience was not matching, I have been passing the id_token instead of access_token. I cannot seem to be able to figure out how to use access_tokens with auth0 correctly. If  anyone has any guideance on this it would be greatly appreciated.
